# Linear algebra - dot product - orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra

Question is from Gilbert 5th 2.1 B:

x+3y+5z=4

x+2y-3z=5

2x+5y+2z=8

[image]

The vector (1,1,-1) is orthogonal to all three columns of A but not to B.

So, take the dot product of each column of A ( and also b) with y = (1,1,-1). How do those dot products show that no combination of columns equals b?

(Sol)
The dot product of each column of A with y = (1,1,-1) is zero.

My question is below:

The dot product should be (1,3,5) * (1,1,-1) = -1, (1,2-3) * (1,1,-1) = 6, and (2,5,2) * (1,1,-1) = 5.
column picture should be (1,1,2) * 1 + (3,2,5) * 1 + (5,-3,2) * -1

I can't get zero.

I believed that I probably misunderstand somewhere.

Comment: You are dotting the **rows** of $A$ with the vector $(1,1,-1)$ not the columns

Comment: You wrote "The vector $(1,1,-1)$ is orthogonal to all three $\textbf{columns}$ of $A$".

Comment: Right! I just totally misunderstand the purpose of this question. Now I got it.  thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

$b$ is a linear combination of the columns of the matrix if there exist $x,y,z$ such that $xC_1+yC_2+zC_3=b.$ Let's denote $u=(1,1,-1).$ Then

$$(xC_1+yC_2+zC_3)\cdot u=xC_1\cdot u +yC_2\cdot +zC_3\cdot u=0$$ while $$b\cdot u\ne 0.$$ So, $b$ is not a linear combination of the columns of the matrix (or in other words, the system is inconsistent).